# Keyboard shows on iPhone 4 on lock screen and home screen

Tags: keyboard, ios

I just upgraded to iOS 7.1. Now there is a permanent keyboard on the lower half of my screen in locked mode and on home screen. How do you get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a glitch — simply reboot to fix it, either by rebooting normally or by doing a hard reset (hold both home & power until the Apple logo appears).

Answer (score 0):

If you swipe from the top to see your notifications, selecting one that wants to open something should present you with the normal lock screen. After unlocking and then re-locking the keyboard went away for me.

Answer (score -1):

I activated Siri, and when Siri went away so did the keyboard.